# Compare two sheets as matrix table

Tags: excel

> A1:200 B1:260
>
> A2:300 B2:220
>
> A3:400 B3:240
>
> A4:200 B4:300
>
> A5:200 B5:200

I got two tables going on and basically I want to check if row A is greater than 200 AND row B is greater than 250 then count.

So far I have this:

> =COUNTIF(A1:A5,">= 200")

but I have no idea how to check if A passes then check B and if so, count it. I'm guessing something to do with IF, AND and maybe a for loop? I'm not familiar with this language at all :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate total count when column A is greater than 200 and B contains cell values greater than 250.

If you want a single value for entire table use countifs,

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5,">200",$B$1:$B$5,">250")
```

If you want to get the counts in different column (let say C) on each row, then copy and paste below formula in C1 and drag it to C5 cell

```
=+IF(AND(A1>200,B1>250),1,0)
```

Where 1 means both conditions are true and 0 means either of condition is false.

However if you want to check first if the first condition is satisfying or not, then you can use below formula:

```
=+IF(A1>200,IF(B1>250,1,0),2)
```

Where "1" means true and both the condtion is satisfying , "0" means first condition is satisfying but second is not and "2" means the first condition is not satisfying hence it didn't check the second condition.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have revised my question to change the numbers up to avoid confusion

Comment: Awesome the first one was exactly what I wanted